# My pregnant wife is experiencing a lot of stress at work due to an incompetent manager. What are her rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

My wife has had a new boss a few months back. He does not understand the role his team plays in the organisation.

He has tried to force (he uses the word encourage) my wife to take up work that is not in the purview of her role.

He has tried to get her to take on work that other teams have to do (this is documented in the process), all under the name of improving working environment.

He has tried to force (again encourage according to him) her to change her personal development goals in the company.

My wife is 5 months into pregnancy and a few days back I had to take her to the A&E after she complained about severe abdominal pains. This followed an extremely stressful 2 hour long meeting with her boss.

I have observed that she is stressed every time there is a meeting with her boss.

What are her legal rights? She does not want to quit her job. She has absolutely no confidence in the HR.

Can she talk to the doctor and get off for a few days without affecting her maternity leave?

Comment: Are you able to edit this into more general terms (something about an adverse work environment and pregnancy is fine) so it doesn't get closed as a request for specific legal advice? The question about workplace rights in a hostile environment is really interesting.  The question about career effects can likely be covered in an answer addressing retribution.

Comment: Asking about effects on her career is definitely off topic here.  Try [workplace.se] for that.